# Subview not getting displayed

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am trying to add a subview using layout constraint. The subview is not getting displayed. Its displaying only when the frame is specified. However I want to achieve the it using  layout constraints

```
import UIKit

class PhotoViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        configurePhotoBarButton()
        buildSubView()
    }

    @objc func closeClicked() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func configurePhotoBarButton() {

        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .lightGray
        navigationItem.title = "Take a Photo"
        let titleAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont(name: "DIN Condensed", size: 30),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleAttributes

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Close", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(closeClicked))
        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont(name: "DIN Condensed", size: 20),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)

    }

    func buildSubView()  {
        //Add a Image View
        let testview = UIView()
        testview.backgroundColor = .orange
        self.view.addSubview(testview)
        testview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        testview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        testview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        testview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. 
Please set it equal `false` when you want to add constraint programmatically.

`testview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`